# Scale Jhipster monolith while using keycloak

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, jhipster, hazelcast, jhipster-registry

I want to use keycloak with my monolith application. Also, I want to scale.

However, when generating a jhipster app, the registry option is not available for choosing OAuth2.

Using registry:

- My primary goal is that hazelcast instances will find each other.
- Config server (optional)

For JWT it just works but what options are available if I want to use an app with oauth2 + jhipster registry?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, looking here: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/4955#issuecomment-278094393 you can see that they think it's incorrect to use oauth2+monolith+registry, although I'm not sure why (not sure at all why oauth2 is implemented stateful...).

Comment: also, If you had any updates since posting the question I'd love to here

Comment: Time has passes. May be we have some options by now. Better we got some answer from jhipster experts here.

Comment: maybe we'll have an update here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54169816/why-is-using-jhipster-oauth2-stateful-and-how-to-implement-it, matt raible is looking at it