# Why is using jhipster oauth2 stateful, and how to implement it?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jhipster, stateless, stateful

Using Jhipster (monolith, oauth2, with registry) forces our users to log-in every once in a while.

After searching a bit, we assume that it's because we have multiple instances of our monolith and sometimes the users get routed to different instances.

So I have 2 questions:

1. Why does Jhipster implement oauth2 in a stateful way?
2. How should we handle this, assuming we're staying with the current configuration?

Comment: What identity server (e.g., Keycloak or Okta) are you using with JHipster? The reason might be because refresh tokens aren't set up properly. Refreshing the access token should happen for you via Spring Security.

Comment: JHipster uses stateful OAuth 2.0 as implemented by Spring Security. Spring Security sets the cookie that makes it so your client doesn't have to store an access token in local storage. That's the stateless alternative we don't implement because implicit flow is not as secure as authorization code flow.

Comment: We're using auth0 as the identity server (actually relatively simple to configure, excluding the current issue).
Where is the refresh token configuration in the jhipster project/spring (endpoint address, rate)?
Is there a way to sync. the cookie between the instances (we're using hazelcast)?

Comment: Also, is there a way to use the implicit flow with oauth2?